# Filter and Reject a List's elements together

Tags: elixir

I have a list of elements that either match a criteria or don't. I know one could use [`Enum.filter`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) or [`Enum.reject`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) to get the list of elements that match / don't match conditions but this would meaning calling both of these methods separately.

**For example**, assume a List of integers (`1..10`), and a boolean method `is_even?`, I would like to get a list (or tuple) of lists of integers grouped as odd and even numbers:

```
[[0,2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7,9]]
```

---

I've looked into [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) but it returns a map with boolean keys, which then has to be mapped on to convert it into a List or a Tuple (and also creates the uncertainty of the order of keys):

```
1..10
|> Enum.group_by(&is_even?/1)
|> Enum.map(fn {_, v} -> v end)

#=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

I'm hoping there's something more terse and cleaner that let's you do this in one go with the certainty of the order of keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39564855/320615?