# Obtain rejected/unfiltered elements from Enum

Tags: elixir

Having for example this list

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

I can filter out the elements which are equal to 4 like this.

```
Enum.reject(list, fn item -> item == 4 end)
```

Is there any way to obtain the rejected items? like `[4, 4]`

Something like:

```
rejected = Enum.get_rejected(list, fn item -> item == 4 end)
more_rejected = Enum.get_rejected(list, fn item -> item == 3 end)
remaining = list
```

I can achieve that right now iterating several times, like:

```
rejected = Enum.filter(list, fn item -> item == 4 end)
more_rejected = Enum.filter(list, fn item -> item == 3 end)
remaining = Enum.reject(list, fn item -> item != 4 and item != 3 end)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564826/elixir-split-list-into-odd-and-even-elements-as-two-items-in-tuple/39564855#39564855 although note that `partition/2` has since been renamed to `split_with/2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enum.split_with/2` to get a tuple of filtered and rejected lists:

```
iex(1)> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
iex(2)> {accepted, rejected} = Enum.split_with(list, fn item -> item == 4 end)
{[4, 4], [1, 2, 3]}
iex(3)> {more_accepted, remaining} = Enum.split_with(rejected, fn item -> item == 3 end)
{[3], [1, 2]}
```